# Please help me translate this sentence into English

Tags: translation

Please help me translate this sentence into English:

> それによりますと、日本はコストが膨大になる有人宇宙船などの開発は行わず、２０２５年ごろから各国が参加して準備が始まるとみられる有人月面探査に日本独自の技術で貢献することで日本人宇宙飛行士の月面到達の権利を得たいとしています。([source](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20170628/k10011033541000.html))

I can only come up with the following:

> According to..., Japan has not built an expensive manned spaceship. Japanese astronauts will be able to earn the qualification to travel to the moon with the contribution of its special technology when countries begin preparation on the moon surface exploration around 2025

Comment: As a rule, translation requests don't typically belong here. That said, people occasionally answer this type of question. Just a quick tip from a moderate newbie.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, looking at the NHK Easy News version makes it a bit clearer (though it is also a good resource if you aren't able to read the normal news comfortably): http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011033541000/k10011033541000.html

For reference, here is the Easy text, though I am basing my translation on both sources:

> ＪＡＸＡによると、日本はお金がかかるため人が乗る宇宙船などはつくらないで、ほかの役に立つ技術を考えて、世界の国が行う宇宙の調査に協力します。そして、日本人の宇宙飛行士を月に送ることができるようにします。

I am not a native speaker, and this translation is not quite literal, but I think it pretty much captures the idea of the sentence:

> "According to JAXA, Japan will not develop a costly manned spacecraft, but will instead contribute specialized technology for the planned 2025 manned moon surface exploration that many countries are participating in, for which preparations are already underway. By providing this support, it is hoped that Japanese astronauts might earn the privilege of making a moon landing."